# Speed up std::cout logging with stringstreams

Tags: c++

I'm trying to speed up a multithreaded program that prints a lot to `std::cout`. Most of the stuff that is printed are strings puzzled together from several variables (strings, numbers etc). Access to `std::cout` is protected by a mutex to prevent printouts from several threads from getting intermingled in the manner of:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    std::cout << stringA << " 1 " << 5  << 'C' << std::endl;
}
```

Measurements showed that several threads spend a lot of time waiting for the mutex as `std::cout` seems to take some time for large and complex strings.

My question now is:

Can I in theory reduce lock contention by assembling the string into a `std::stringstream` before entering the mutex, then send the already assembled string to `std::cout`? As in:

```
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << stringA << " 1 " << 5  << 'C' << std::endl;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    std::cout << ss.str();
}
```

If yes, can this be improved further?

Comment: Depending on how much work you actually do when building your string, I would *guess* that calling `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` has a bigger effect.

Comment: For starters, use `\n` instead of `endl` and try untying `cout` from `cin`. If that helps, the problem wasn't multi threading.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: the `tie()` _from_ `std::cin` to `std::cout` only matter when _reading_: prior to reading `std::cin` flushes the `tie()`d stream. If only output is used the `tie()` shouldn't matter. Not using `std::endl` is reasonable, though (actually: [it is never reasonable to use `std::endl`](https://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/))

Comment: @DietmarKühl Ah right, my bad. Thanks.

Comment: It has been the subject of many arguments in my career whether one should use the C sprintf and its ilk for logging as opposed to sticking with streams. My own opinion through profiling and experience is that sprintf is indeed much faster, although it has some error handling and maintainablity concerns that one should familiarize one's self with, particularly when creating one's own wrapper using variadic arguments. If you were on my team, I would attempt to persuade you to not use streams and instead use C constructs for logging where perfomance matters.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz I would strongly recommend you don't do that. The C APIs are really not nice (easy to cause UB, for example). Use one of the much faster formatting and/or logging libraries already out there, such as [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)

Comment: @ChristopherPisz: ... and I would do the opposite! I'm aware that streams are easy to use badly but on the positive side the misuses only cause the program to go slower than possible rather than resulting in memory corruption.

Comment: @justin I was not aware there was a text formatting proposal in the works. I can only hope they give us a more performant standard option in the future. I shall profile this library you proposed. Thanks!

Comment: @Dietmar I haven't had a case that I investigated were I could say there was any "misuse", where streams could compete with the C APIs. I argued for streams for 10 years, but had to conform given the evidence. I accepted the error prone-ed-ness as a trade off. If you could provide something to profile, where they are used "correctly" and give equal or better results while formatting primitive types, I'd be very interested. I hate variadic arguments and the fact that you can pass an Elephant when an integer is expected.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz: I haven't run things since quite a while and it seems things slightly changed. At [cputube](https://github.com/dietmarkuehl/cputube) I got a rather naive approach for writing an array of `int`s using different approaches. With gcc/libstdc++ I don't see substantial difference between the basic IOStreams and stdio approaches. clang/libc++ is known to have a *bad* implementation of IOStreams as is Visual Studio with its default library. I haven't tried my [own implementation](http://dietmar-kuehl.de/cxxrt/) and I guess it doesn't even compile but I'd expect it to be fastest.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz: I tried the run just now on a Macbook and a Raspberry PI (neither ideal platforms) but the results are consistent with what I remember from a few years back where I tried it on more reasonable systems, too. I may be doing something really silly to make IOStreams not look entirely bad but I'm happy to learn.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I'd like to discuss these comparisons some, but I don't see an option on S.O. to message you. Where can we have some dialog back and forth, since comp.lang.C++ is gone?

Comment: @ChristopherPisz: obviously I would like to discuss on comp.lang.c++**.moderated** (as I am/was a moderator of this bewsgroup) but it doesn’t exist anymore. On SO we could discuss on the chats which can work reasonably well: either C++Longe - an open chat where other also could be involved (but we’d interfere with their conversation) or a custom chat. I don’t know whether these are open. We’d need to pick some time, though (for me some time this Friday to Monday would be good  as I’ll not be at work). ... and I get asked to move the discussion to a chat already! :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178162/discussion-between-dietmar-kuhl-and-christopher-pisz).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I in theory reduce lock contention by assembling the string into a std::stringstream before entering the mutex, then send the already assembled string to std::cout?

Absolutely. `operator<<` has to do some work to format the types passed in. Assembling the string into a `std::stringstream` means that you do all that work up front and just have to write out the assembled string to `std::cout`, meaning you spend less time under the lock.

However, note that `ss.str()` returns a `std::string` by value. This means that you are copying the string inside the critical region. It would be better to write `std::cout << ss.rdbuf()` and write the underlying string inside the `std::stringstream` directly.

Beyond that, you'll want to reduce the time spent outputting to `std::cout` as much as possible. If you never call any C stdio functions, you should probably call `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`

Bringing this together:

```
// Near the beginning of your program:
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

// ...

{
    // Prefer using ostringstream if you never need to read from it
    std::ostringstream ss;
    // std::endl is never needed. Use '\n' instead. If you want to flush,
    // explicitly write `ss << '\n' << std::flush`. For stringstreams, I believe
    // it doesn't matter, but it's good to get into the habit of doing this
    ss << stringA << " 1 " << 5  << 'C' << '\n';
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    std::cout << ss.rdbuf();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I shall take both suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I would drop string streams altogether in favor of `std::string::append` and `std::to_string`. streams tend to drag a lot of locale-oriented stuff and make the implementation heavier than the raw string operations. I would go with  this:

```
 std::string str;
 str.append(stringA).append(" 1 ").append('C').append('\n');
 std::cout << str;
```

Comment: This often doesn't work, though. Sometimes you need formatted output, and even the example in the OP outputs the integer `5`, which requires some sort of formatted output.

Comment: @Justin: `str.append(std::to_string(5));`

Comment: @DietmarKühl Yes, but note that does require creating a `std::string` just for that (doesn't allocate due to SSO, but with large enough ints, it could). It also doesn't work in general for arbitrary types.

Comment: It's a mistake from the Q not yours, but you don't need a to lock a mutex; all major C++ library implementations have `std::cout` lock internally. Solid point about using strings being potentially faster though: as well as locales there's heavy use of virtual dispatch.  Justin's right about formatted output though - setting precisions, widths and other iomanip stuff in particular.

Comment: @TonyDelroy I removed the mutex. it was actually needed in the first snippet of the OP as he wanted to prevent from several threads to print into the same line.

Comment: @DavidHaim: oh true - I didn't look back that far in the Q.  Cheers

Comment: @DavidHaim I'm not convinced that removing the mutex is valid. It appears to me that you might get interleaved characters if you do so: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio